# Is it possible to extend the Object class to know how many objects I currently have

Tags: java, class, object

Is it possible to extend the Object class to know how many objects I currently have? Like adding , `static count = 0`, and increasing it in its constructor when an object is created?

Comment: What is the Object class?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I just noticed that it's irrelevant to C++, I'll edit my tags to Java.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: You can get that information from  `jconsole` via JMX. You don't need coding tricks.

Comment: You can, but this will be your `CustomObject`, not plain Java `Object`

Comment: @LouisWasserman You could have it working for your hierarchy of objects, but you can't match all those types that inherits directly from `Object` instead of your counter class (ie the ones standard library)

Comment: On the other hand, what the OP probably _wants_ looks more like https://github.com/google/allocation-instrumenter.

Comment: Thanks guys. that helped much.

Comment: @skypjack Which is to say that it's not possible.

Comment: @EJP Well, it depends on the actual problem. If you want to count only objects from your hierarchy, it works just fine.